# How do I get the value of Total No. of Transaction and Sum of Transaction from below string using oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

```json
{
  "timestamp": 1654752742887,
  "status": "OK",
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": "GET response successful.",
  "content": [
    {
      "Total No. of Transaction": 1,
      "Sum of Transaction": 473
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a JSON value which can be invoked from a SQL SELECT statement and extracted through use of `JSON_TABLE()` function such as

```
WITH t(js) AS
(
 SELECT '{
           "timestamp": 1654752742887,
           "status": "OK",
           "statusCode": 200,
           "message": "GET response successful.",
           "content": [
             {
               "Total No. of Transaction": 1,
               "Sum of Transaction": 473
             }
           ]
         }' 
   FROM dual
)
 SELECT "Total No. of Transaction", "Sum of Transaction" 
   FROM t,
        JSON_TABLE(js, '$'
                        COLUMNS (NESTED PATH '$.content[*]'
                        COLUMNS ("Total No. of Transaction" VARCHAR2 PATH '$."Total No. of Transaction"', 
                                 "Sum of Transaction"       VARCHAR2 PATH '$."Sum of Transaction"') 
                   ));
```

| Total No. of Transaction | Sum of Transaction |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 473 |

provided that the DB version is at least `12.1.0.2`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d9ba37fb588bbda02396c29928e3781a)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

That's a JSON, so you'd

```
SQL> select t.col.content."Total No. of Transaction" total_no,
  2         t.col.content."Sum of Transaction" sum_of_trans
  3  from test t;

TOTAL_NO        SUM_OF_TRANS
--------------- ---------------
1               473

SQL>
```